# What's a better way to integrate this?

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2 + z^2} dx $$

I tried substitution and also by parts. By parts is getting messy and I am not sure if I am getting the right answer. I am trying to figure out an easier way or the proper way to integrate this. Could someone please show me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right substitution will do the job for you. Set $x = z \tan(t)$. We then have $dx = z \sec^2(t) dt$. Hence,
$$\int \dfrac{dx}{x^2+z^2} = \int \dfrac{z \sec^2(t) dt}{z^2(\tan^2(t)+1)} = \dfrac1z \int \dfrac{\sec^2(t) dt}{\sec^2(t)} = \dfrac{t}z + \text{const} = \dfrac{\arctan(x/z)}z + \text{const}$$
We made use of the following two facts in the above derivation.

- $\dfrac{d(\tan(t))}{dt} = \sec^2(t)$
- $\tan^2(t)+1 = \sec^2(t)$

Comment: I am really bad with trig functions. So could you explain what did you do here? Are you using trig substitution?

Comment: @user77696 Yes, we do a trigonometric substitution in this case. I have added the couple of trigonometric identities, we have used in the proof.

Comment: I took the time to review trig sub, and it wasn't as hard as I remembered. This is definitely powerful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the substitution $u= x/z$. Then you get
$$
\frac{1}{z} \int \frac{1}{u^2 + 1} du = \frac{1}{z} \arctan\left(\frac{x}{z}\right) + C.
$$